# Configuring Python to avoid conflict with ArcGIS for Desktop (ArcPy)?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, arcpy, python-2.7, python-toolbox

I am trying to find the best way to configure a new version of python in my computer (windows) so that I do not have any problem with the python version that I have with ArcGIS. Is there anyway to have two versions of python and install/run anything on version 2 (say version 1 is my ArcGIS version)without having a conflict? I had to reinstall ArcGIS before due to this conflict. I am a beginner in programming and so please be patient if I am not making sense here.

Comment: Can I ask why? you can install two different version of python together (e.g. version 2.7 and 3) but I don't think installing python 2.7 twice is possible. Why not using python that is installed with Arcgis for other purposes?

Comment: If you're a beginner at programming then multiple installs of python (probably) isn't something you should really be considering - advanced users of python and programmers are cringing at the thought! However if you desperately need a second version try Windows Virtual PC - that way it's guaranteed not to interfere.

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson Unfortunately, I understand the need for multiple installs of Python.  For example, good luck trying to install Python's scikit-image module on top of the Esri python distribution. Often packages such as scikit-image require different versions of numpy.  Of course, if you alter the numpy version, Arc will not work properly...

Comment: @Aaron, me too. But I'm not a beginner. Virtual PC is a good way to keep the installs 100% separate and is *much* easier to instruct than setting environment variables, controlling library installs into different versions and starting python with a DOS batch script. There may be better ways but that works for me simply... it also means I can have more than one ArcGis install to test my programs on without having to have lots of computers (just beware each virtual PC will consume 1 floating license, so it's easy to make lots of other Esri users angry).

Comment: Thanks to you all for quick response!! Okay, so here is the story. I messed up my ArcGIS trying to work outside the python shell in ArcGIS few months ago. I do not remember exactly where it all started. I think I was trying to install scipy-numpy, gdal that sort of things using it from outside the ArcGIS shell. But after a few days when I tried to use Python from within ArcGIS, it was all messed up. I remember spending few days trying to install and re-install and then figuring out (basically reading in some forums) that I messed up with my ArcGIS python.

Comment: What was suggested and fixed the problem was uninstalling the python and GIS completely and then re-installing GIS again. Now I do not want to go through that again and that is why trying to get guidance on how best to use it. Say ifI want to install scipy-numpy, what will work and not mess up my GIS?

Comment: and what about virtualenv? I heard it somewhere that it works, am I saying something completely wrong? Hope you all will lead me here..

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson Good idea testing new software on a virtual PC.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion about the virtual PC. I will spend sometime trying to figure this out. I think once you create a virtual PC, you can assign only fraction of the hard drive space, correct? Secondly, if I want to use IPython, when I have ArcGIS what would be the best way to use it? I know these are all newbie questions but some help would be appreciated!!

Comment: virtual PC does not seem like a good solution to me, after I spent little time reading about and installing it. Is there any other solution anyone can think about?

Comment: This is exactly the use case for virtualenv.